# JAVA home give me wrong value on Jenkins node

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins node with below configuration for JavaPath:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java
```

I wrote a simple Jenkins job which does the following:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}"
echo $PATH
```

for some reason, the output I'm getting is:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31
```

why it doesn't use the value which used to load node?

Comment: Looks like `JAVA_HOME` is the path to the Java installation while the "JavaPath" is the path to the binary executable named `java` (?) ... Are you sure that the variable should be named "JavaPath" to get picked up and propagate as an environment variable? How is it a "real problem" for you, any stacktrace for some actual task or are you just needing to know? Did you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185593/jenkins-specifying-java-home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got response from SO forum: Is there a `JAVA_HOME` configured under `Mange Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> JDK`? You may have to click on `JDK installations` to be able to see what's configured there.